# How to change the bar chart orientation in Google Charts

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-visualization

I need to draw two bar charts facing each other in one page. (The chart on the left faces right, and the one on the right faces left).

But with Google Charts, I only managed to make both charts face right.

Is it possible to implement? What should I do?

Comment: @WhiteHat I've thought about div flipping, but wouldn't that flips the text as well? Could you tell me more about what you mean by manipulating the data or chart elements? Thanks!

Comment: using a 100% stacked chart, make the first series, or two, on the left transparent

Comment: @WhiteHat That's a good idea. :) But the vertical axie will still be on the left side, and the values on the horizontal axie won't match with the bars' true value, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a 100% stacked chart, you can get the bars to align to the right

then color the first series transparent,
and manipulate the data to reveal the proper length

then when the chart's `'ready'` event fires,
you can move around the chart elements,
such as the y-axis, and the order of the x-axis labels

first, you need to allow enough room on the left,
for the original y-axis labels to print
otherwise they will be cutoff, i.e.

`Canis Major Dwarf` vs. `Canis Maj...`

then need to leave enough room on the right,
by limiting the `chartArea`, otherwise cutoff and simply not visible, i.e.

`Canis Major Dwarf` vs. `Canis M`

might be easier, providing your own labels

this should give you something to tweak on...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

function drawStuff() {
  var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Galaxy', 'Distance', 'Brightness'],
    ['Canis Major Dwarf', 10, 20],
    ['Sagittarius Dwarf', 20, 40],
    ['Ursa Major II Dwarf', 40, 50],
    ['Lg. Magellanic Cloud', 60, 80],
    ['Bootes I', 80, 120]
  ]);

  var options = {
    isStacked: 'percent',
    colors: ['transparent', 'magenta'],
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom'
    },
    chartArea: {
      left: 200,
      width: 400
    },
    width: 800
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('dual_x_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(container);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var labels = container.getElementsByTagName('text');
    var hAxisLabels = [];
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(labels, function (text, index) {
      switch (text.getAttribute('text-anchor')) {
        // move y axis labels
        case 'end':
          text.setAttribute('x', parseFloat(text.getAttribute('x')) + 540);
          break;

        // save x axis labels
        case 'middle':
          // save x position here
          // otherwise, x position will change
          // before you know where the next should have been
          hAxisLabels.push({
            text: text,
            x: parseFloat(text.getAttribute('x'))
          });
          break;
      }
    });
    
    // swap label positions
    hAxisLabels.forEach(function (label, index) {
      label.text.setAttribute('x', hAxisLabels[hAxisLabels.length - index - 1].x);      
    });
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dual_x_div"></div>
```

Comment: still need to left align y-axis labels, etc. -- like i said in the original comment, serious manipulation to get everything aligned properly...